# Am I missing the simple way to run Kotlin's Iterable extension functions in parallel?

Tags: kotlin, concurrency, iterable

I love the many extension functions for Kotlin's [Iterable](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-iterable/) and am hoping there is a standard function somewhere that will turn any `Iterable` into a `CoIterable` that runs everything from `any()` to `map()` in parallel, as most devices have many apparent cores these days. All tested and debugged and beautiful.

And yet, if it exists, it is evading not only my Google and my SO foos, but also SO's "Similar questions".

Comment: Can you check if `.stream().parallel()` or `.parallelStream()` works for you? Also I guess by `CoIterable` you mean some hypothetical Coroutin'ified collection?

Comment: Thanks, will do. 

Yes, I am looking for a library, where each and every ```Iterable``` extension function is safely and automagically run in parallel on a thread pool. While it may be very imaginary, it continues to seem rather Kotlinesque, at least to me.

Comment: Fair expectation. `.stream().parallel()` might be the closest to what you expect. As for Kotlin, (1) coroutines do not make things parallel, they just facilitate (2) corouti'nified functions have non-compatible signatures. So `int Count()` is not the same as `suspend Count() : Int`. Also if the object implements interfaces or extends base classes with one definition, it is nontrivial to use the _other_ definition with it.

Comment: I don't think this is the sort of thing they'll ever put into the standard library because it's too specialized. None of the standard Iterables are thread-safe, so you would need some kind of synchronization lock while performing the operation. But the kind of lock you need and how you use it is going to depend on what kind/how much data is in the collection, and how you have set up your thread-safety, one of myriad possible ways.

Comment: I think you're overcomplicating it,Tenfour04. I am only imagining a single operation, setting up its result, enqueueing a ()->{} for each item, and waiting for each proc to terminate. Some functions will not need any more locking than that: if they create a fixed size list, each proc knows where to put its result, and will not conflict with any other. Functions that grow a list (like ```filter()```) or return maps need to lock the overall result before adding each item's value.